# Jenkins and Cisco Anyconnect on OS X server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cisco

I have a customer that is using Cisco's Anyconnect as a vpn client in front of the repository I need to pull from. I am trying to find out if Jenkins has a plugin for Cisco's Anyconnect or a solution to get the automation past it? I suggested that the repository be mirrored to my github, but that has not happened yet.

Is there a way to install Cisco Anyconnect from the command line and have a shell script pass the credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I use vpnc. On some maven builds I have Pre and Post Steps, for any builds I can do execute 
shell and rearrange the order.

I would highly recommend installing vpnc via RPM or some easy installer. Configurations are in /etc/vpnc/

Sample Cisco PROD.conf file

```
IPSec gateway 172.0.0.1
IPSec ID admin
IPSec secret 12345ABC
Xauth username jenkins
Xauth password hunter2
```

You have to have disable RSA tokens if using this process. Keep in mind this file should only be owned by root at 600 permission level.

Add this to /etc/sudoers:

```
jenkins     ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/local/sbin/vpnc*
```

In some situations VPNs will cause absolute havoc with other jobs on the server. Consider running on an exclusive slave or change your jenkins executor to one.

Pre Script:

```
 echo "Stopping VPN.\n";
 sudo /usr/local/sbin/vpnc-disconnect || true;
 echo "Starting VPN to (Production datacenter).\n";
 sudo /usr/local/sbin/vpnc prod;
```

Post Script:

```
echo "Stopping VPN.\n";
sudo /usr/local/sbin/vpnc-disconnect || true;
```